# Is there a Google Datastore adapter which is used to access Datastore in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-datastore

In rails, we can use adapter of sqlite3 to access sqlite3 database.
Now I want to use Datastore as my database.
Is there a Google Datastore adapter like sqlite3's ?

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
```

Comment: https://github.com/Agrimatics/active-model-cloud-datastore

Answer (score 0):

Has it been tried? Yes. 
Is it a good idea? **Probably not.**

ActiveRecord is a Object Relational Manager which is built around relational SQL databases. The SQLite adapter is a an adapter that lets ActiveRecord talk to SQLite. While you can easily swap it for a MySQL, Postgresql or Oracle adapter going over to no-sql land is not as smooth sailing.

There is a reason separate Rails ORMs like Mongoid for MongoDB exist. The concepts in a non-relational database are very different and not something that really should be abstracted away by an adapter.

Comment: There is no ORM yet for Google Cloud Datastore AFAIK. If you really want to use rails I would suggest you use some other nosql option like MongoDB or Rethink. There is a Cloud Datastore SDK but it is far from an ORM and you will need write every query from scratch or basically create your own ORM.

Comment: There is a pretty good discussion here on why a ActiveRecord adapter is not really feasible https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/issues/617

Answer (score 0):

This was just released:
[Agrimatics/activemodel-datastore](https://github.com/Agrimatics/activemodel-datastore)

"Ruby on Rails with Active Model and Google Cloud Datastore. Extracted from Agrimatics Aero."

Haven't tried it myself, so I can't vouch for it. But it sounds like what you are looking for.